# Java Basics: Required int[ ], Found int (Bad Operations)

Tags: java

**Question: How can I fix my code. What is causing the problems/Can I get an example. NOT the answer.**
*One of my Tasks are to: "Declare but not initialize the two fields"*

*I am new to Java Programming, So please keep your answers simple to read.*

**Basic Outline:**
I am trying to write a basic program that reads number of Years Served and Displays to the screen, how many Days of Vacation they would receive.

***Error Message:***
The current Error messages I am receiving is:

**Line 27:** 
bad operand types for binary operator '>=', first type:  int[], second type: int

**Line 28:** incompatible types
  required: int
  found:    int[]

**Line 30:** bad operand types for binary operator '>='
  , first type:  int[]
  , second type: int

**Line 36:** reached end of file while parsing

*Here is my code:*

```
public class VacationScale {
    public int[] vacationDays;
    public int[] yearsOfService;


    public void setVacationScale() {
        vacationDays = new int[7];
        vacationDays[0] = 10;
        vacationDays[1] = 15;
        vacationDays[2] = 15;
        vacationDays[3] = 15;
        vacationDays[4] = 20;
        vacationDays[5] = 20;
        vacationDays[6] = 25;
    }

    public void displayVacationDays() {
        if (yearsOfService >= 0 && yearsOfService < 6) {
            System.out.println("Number of Vacation Days: " + vacationDays[yearsOfService]);

    } else if (yearsOfService >= 6) {
            System.out.println("Number of Vacation Days: " + vacationDays[6]);

    } else {
        System.out.println("Invaild Years if Service");
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You defined yearsOfService as an array of int, but use it as a simple int. Change it from int[] to int.

Comment: you are missing a parantheis for the end of the method `displayVacationDays` and you try to compare an array of `int` to a single int, which isn´t possible.

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question. (And the implied "fix my code" is not a real question)

Comment: Question: How can I fix my code. What is causing the problems/Can I get an example. NOT the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (yearsOfService >= 0 && yearsOfService < 6) {
```

Here when you use logical operators, you can't compare the array yearsOfService with a number.

Depending on your requirement, you should declare `yearsOfService` as an `int`.

Comment: So would you say something alone the lines of:                                           `if (yearsOfService[0] >= 0 && yearsOfService[6] < 6) {`

Comment: Yes, that should also compile. But first initialize the yearsOfService array with something.

Comment: One of my Tasks are to: "Declare but not initialize the two fields"

Comment: Which means I am not able to initialize the `yearsOfService` array with anything. Within the code is when its men't to happen.

Comment: Since yearsOfService is an instance variable, it will be automatically initialized to null when your object instance is created. So yearsOfService[0] will fail.